# Wordpress custom post type Monthly archive

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called 'press_release'

I have a few posts, and viewing them uses the 'single-press_release.php' template file. This all works fine, however i want to have a monthly archive list for just this post type.

```
<?php wp_get_archives();?>
```

Displaying this in my single-press_release.php page displays a monthly archive list for standard blog posts, and not the press releases, how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_get_archives` doesn't work with custom post types. Check this discussion: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/archive-list-and-page-for-custom-post-types-mysql?replies=9